# Grails deletes referenced records by other domain object?

Tags: grails, dns, grails-orm

I am a bit puzzled on the following..

A domain model consists of a Person who has Addresses, these Address 
can also be referenced by other Persons..

So Person A has addresses 1, 2, 3 and Person B has adresses 1, 4 ,5 
No when i delete Person A, Person B also loses his address 1!! I was 
under the impression that the cascade: 'all-delete-orphan' was meant 
for these kind off situations. But probably i am making a mistake! 
How can i tackle this?

```
class Person { 
    Address address 
    Address addressPostal 
    Address addressInvoice 

    static mapping = { 
          address cascade:'all-delete-orphan' 
          addressPostal cascade:'all-delete-orphan' 
          addressInvoice cascade:'all-delete-orphan' 
    } 
} 

class Address { 
    String street 
    String streetNo 
    String streetSuffix 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `all-delete-orphan` works the other way.  When you remove the *many* object from the collection on the *one* side, the object gets auto-deleted.  Otherwise, it would just get "orphaned" with `null` as the foreign key.

You could use it the other way.  For example, Address had a `static hasMany = [persons: Person]` and you removed the person from it, `all-delete-orphan` would remove the Person.